# creating a stored procedure and need to clear by corporation id

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure that does the following:

```
if CorporationId = xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx then
 clear transactions from x days back
if CorporationId = yyyyy-yyyy-yyyyy-yyyy-yyyyy then
 clear transactions from x days back
else 
 clear transactions from x days back
end if
```

That's the idea behind what I want to do. I want to be able to take a specific CorporationID guid and have their settings altered for just them but leave a default for everyone else.

This is what I have so far but I'm not familiar enough with tsql to finish it:

```
DELETE FROM [Truck].[GpsReading] WHERE [DateTimeOfReading] <= DATEADD(DAY, -14, GetDate()) and PNRef IS NULL
```

That's the delete part but I'm not sure how to do the if checks.

I did see the Microsoft ["else if else"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx) article. I couldn't figure out how that comes in to play here when I want to specify the CorporationId before the start of the stored procedure.

Is there a way to do it the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

Where does the "X days back" come from? do you have a settings table?
Assuming you do have a settings table you could do something like

```
DECLARE @daysBack int = 0

SELECT @daysBack = PeriodToClear from settings where CorporationId = @CorporationId

DELETE FROM [Truck].[GpsReading] WHERE [DateTimeOfReading] <= DATEADD(DAY, @daysBack, GetDate()) and PNRef IS NULL
AND CorporationId = @CorporationId
```

@CorporationId is the parameter that you pass to your Store Procedure

The last check for me makes sense are by the looks of it you have more data on the same table than that particular CorporationId.